# If player leaves a rectangle take him back to his previous position

Tags: java

Okay, I'm making a game. The map contains all the blocks/buildings/structures etc... The map is bordered by a rectangle.

So what I want is if the player attempts to exit the rectangle he goes back to where he was. This way he cannot leave the map.

My attempt's output (right side), this one is perfect:
[image]

But the left side is not perfect:
[image]

My code:

public class Player extends GameObject{

```
BufferedImageLoader loader;
Texture tex = Game.getInstance();
BufferedImage image;
Animation playerWalkLeft;
private HealthBarManager healthBar;
private String username;
private int width;
private ManaBarManager manaBar;

public Player(float x, float y, ObjectID ID) {
    super(x, y, ID, null);
    loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
    playerWalkLeft = new Animation(5,tex.player[10],tex.player[11],tex.player[12],tex.player[13],tex.player[14],tex.player[15],tex.player[17],tex.player[18]);

}

public void tick(LinkedList<GameObject> object) {

    setX(getX()+velX);
    setY(getY()+velY);


    playerWalkLeft.runAnimation();


}

public void render(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(g.getFont());

    if(username != null) width = fm.stringWidth(username);
    if(username != null){
        g.drawString(username,(int) x-width/2+15,(int) y);
    }


    if(velX != 0){
        playerWalkLeft.drawAnimation(g, (int)x, (int)y);
    }else{
        g.drawImage(tex.player[16], (int)x, (int)y,  null);

    }


    g.setColor(Color.PINK);
    g.drawRect((int)x,(int)y,33,48);
    g.drawRect(0,0,(int)Game.getWalkableBounds().getWidth(), (int)Game.getWalkableBounds().getHeight());


}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Image getCurrentImage() {
    return image;
}

public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setX(float x) {


    if(isPlayerInsideBoundry(x,y)){
        this.x = x;
    }


}

public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public float getVelX() {
    return velX;
}

public void setHealthBar(HealthBarManager healthBar){
    this.healthBar = healthBar;
}

public HealthBarManager getHealthBar(){
    return healthBar;
}

public float getVelY() {
    return velY;
}

public void setVelX(float velX) {
    this.velX = velX;
}

public void setVelY(float velY) {
    this.velY = velY;
}

public ObjectID getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setUsername(String playerName) {
    this.username = playerName;

}

public String getUsername(){
    return this.username;

}

public void setManaBar(ManaBarManager manaBar) {
    this.manaBar = manaBar;

}

public ManaBarManager getManaBar(){
    return manaBar;
}

public int getLevel(){
    return 1;
}


public boolean isPlayerInsideBoundry(float x, float y){
    Rectangle boundry = Game.getWalkableBounds();


    if(boundry.contains(x,y)){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public Rectangle getBounds(String boundType){
    if(boundType.equalsIgnoreCase("left")){
        return new Rectangle((int)x,(int)y,33/2,44/2);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should do is to calculate the new position of the player if he moves and then check, if the new position is inside the boudry.
If the position is inside the boundry apply the new position to the player postion , if not just don't apply the new coordinates.

With this method it is not possible for the player to leave the boundry .

Hope I could help :)

Comment: This won't work:
http://pastebin.com/ByZv1JAc Since it is a rectangle I can't be sure if the player is attempting to exit the left border or the right border.

Comment: I've updated my code, the result isn't perfect. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably some of the easiest implementation would be something like this (pseudo code):

```
var lastValidPosition = player.getPosition();

...

if (positionIsValid(player.getPosition())) {
    lastValidPosition = player.getPosition;
}
else {
    player.setPosition(lastValidPosition);
}
```

Just note that this won't be the perfect strategy to restrain the player from entering specific areas based on the player's ability to move different distances between checks. For example, you might be 1 pixel away from the border, the player moves 2 pixels between checks, then you'd never be able to actually reach the border.

For such cases, you'd most likely want to either check smaller iterations or - in the case of some global boundary - just do some min/max comparison:

```
// Keep the player from passing the left boundary:
player.x = max(player.x, leftboundary);

// Keep the player from passing the right boundary:
player.x = min(player.x, rightboundary);
```

You could put both into one line of course, maybe even adding the actual movement code as well:

```
// Update player's x position
player.x = max(min(player.x + movementX, rightboundary), leftboundary);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to keep this architecture as it is right now, you should create a copy of the position of the player everytime you verified it being legal and save it to a variable. Should a future check turn out to be illegal, you can use that saved value to reset to the last known legal position.

However, I would advise you to tackle the issue differently. Add a check into the setter* of the position of your player character which checks whether or not the new position is valid. When it isn't, don't perform the set. You might want to signal this to the caller by throwing an exception.

*You *are* using a `setPosition` method to change the position of the player-character and not just public variables, are you?